# Better search, like the one that Ask a question has

Tags: feature-request

To find something on SO en SF, I always 'abuse' the Ask Question form, because it gives me immediately feedback on existing topics. If I don't see my question listed, I can then refine my question. If it's still not there I publish the question. My question here is, why can't we get that functionality as the default search option?

Answer (score 1):

That form simply searches by title only.

If you want that, use the advanced search options

https://serverfault.com/search

for example

https://serverfault.com/search?q=example+intitle:1

Comment: thanks. i'm just  some sort of noob that gets headaches from 'Advanced Super Ninja Search Options' ie typing lots of [] and : in a searchbox (makes me having to think, and I hate thinking on websites). I think I'll stick to my current habits then, though I have to admit that the extra search options are powerful :-)

Comment: You might be on the wrong Web sites if you don't like to think.